# Language with types as first-class values?

Tags: functional-programming

Is there a language, which is:

1) functional

2) has type inference

3) has currying

4) and has types as first-class values

also would like to compile from it to JVM and/or CLR

Comment: Java supports reflection, so...

Comment: Yes, but it has no type inference and currying.

Comment: You can curry easily in any language that has closures: `curry(f,x) => ((y) => f(x,y))`

Comment: (2) and (4) seem to be pretty much mutually exclusive.

Comment: [Mercury](http://www.mercury.csse.unimelb.edu.au/index.html) is the closest I can think, but not exact match.

Comment: @JanDvorak "Java... You can curry easily in any language that has closures". Does Java have closures?

Comment: @JonHarrop It doesn't (yet, but it will in 6-8 weeks). Please interpret "Java supports reflection" as "the JVM supports reflection", not as "the Java language supports reflection".

Comment: @JanDvorak We're talking about closures, not reflection. Are you saying that Java will get closures in 6-8 weeks?

Comment: @JonHarrop yes. 6-8 weeks basically means "it's always on the roadmap". Until Java 7, closures would be in Java 7. Now they're planned for Java 8. When Java 8 is released, they might be in Java 9...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

F# is functional and has type inference, currying and types as first-class values in the sense that you can dissect types at run-time via reflection. It compiles to the CLR and works well on Mono.

**EXAMPLE: Taken from my (non-free) article [Structural Typing](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/structural-typing.html) in the [F#.NET Journal](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/products/fsharp_journal/)**:

The following `createType` function creates a new .NET assembly, new module and new public class type of the given name:

```
> let createType typeName =
    let name = System.Reflection.AssemblyName(Name="tmpAssembly")
    let run = System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run
    let builder = System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(name, run)
    let mdl = builder.DefineDynamicModule "tmpModule"
    let attrs = TypeAttributes.Public ||| TypeAttributes.Class
    mdl.DefineType(typeName, attrs);;
val createType : string -> TypeBuilder
```

Comment: It also has the idea of Type Providers: effectively compiler extensions that can generate types from metadata at compile time. I.e. strongly typed representations of database schemas or OData server query results based on the metadata those services provided to the Type Provider at code compilation time.

Comment: I just like to add @mavnn 's comment that type provider also helps to write java script in F#, so you have F# everywhere just like node but also with all the goodness of typed multi-threaded language.

Comment: Can I produce new types at runtime with `F#`? For example, Cartesian product of types `A` and `B`?

Comment: @SuzanCioc Yes, you can create new types using reflection. However, that type will only be available at run-time so I cannot think of any practical application of doing that.

Comment: @Jon can you give an example here please? My separate question about this was disliked by a public: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549244/how-to-create-new-type-at-runtime-in-f

Comment: @SuzanCioc Sure. I've added an excerpt from an article I wrote about implementing structural typing in F# using, amongst other things, run-time generated types to create concrete implementations of interfaces when existing types adhere to an interface of your own. Note that F# itself does this when you use an object expression to implement an interface without using a class.

Comment: @Jon thanks. I am expecting that language with first-class valued types should be able to create new type with 1 line: `let A = B*C` where `A`, `B` and `C` are types.

Comment: @SuzanCioc - try `let tyA = typedefof<_*_>.MakeGenericType(tyB, tyC)`.  But it would be helpful if you could expand on a realistic goal that you're hoping to achieve.  Why do you want types created at runtime, and what do you hope to do with them?

Answer (score 7):

I just started learning it but [Coq](http://coq.inria.fr/) might work for you.

It's quite possible to have a function which takes in a type (yes a raw type, not an instance of that type) and return another type (again, just the type, not an instance). If you're at all interested in formal verification of programs it's worth a look.

It also has the nice little benefit of being able to convert it's code to Haskell/OCaml/Scheme so that you can use their IO/Libraries since Coq tends lacks them.

It has type inference and currying but the type inference isn't perfect as the language's type system is well beyond (and more expressive than) a standard Milner-Hindley type system.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), it works on both JVM and .NET. Here is some features including what you seek - http://www.scala-lang.org/node/104, look at "Scala is functional" section, "Local Type Inference", "Currying" and "Predefined function classOf" articles, also it has top type [Any](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Any), pattern matching for values *and* types, [reflect](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.package) package.

Comment: Scala looks having poor type inference. For example, function argument types are not inferenced.

Comment: While early versions of Scala compiled to .NET, current versions do not. Also, I'm a little confused about your comment regarding function arguments not being inferred. How would that work? Inference based on the members referenced in the scope of the function?

Answer (score -1):

First start from [wikipedia type interference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference). Answer for this question seems to be Haskell or OCaml.

Comment: Ocaml has no types as first class values don't know about Haskell.

Comment: @SuzanCioc first-class types can be handled via reflection. Is that sufficient for you?

Comment: Can I produce new types with reflection?

Comment: @SuzanCioc Try to see http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/reflection/0.2.0/doc/html/Data-Reflection.html

Comment: The `reflection` package is something entirely different from the reflection being asked about.