# How to create new type at runtime in F#?

Tags: reflection, f#, runtime

Please give an example of how to create new type (say, two types Cartesian product) in F# at runtime with reflection?

**UPDATE**

I am looking for a language with first class types. I was told F# can this. I tried nothing since didn't learned F# yet. I just want to see how it's made.

Comment: What have you tried? You can just search the web for some sample code in C#, and it's easy to port it to F#. If you try it and get stuck somewhere, post what you've tried and we can help you work it out.

Comment: Oops. I was just in the middle of writing an answer when the question got closed. You can see what I wrote so far here: http://pastebin.com/ZngRvM3y

Comment: @TomasPetricek it's a pity this question got closed, because I really like your answer: it's what I was looking for! Thanks for posting it in a comment :)

Answer (score 6):

The following F# code takes 2 sequences of values (rank and suit in the example)  and returns the cartesian product as a sequence of pairs (cards), using a pair type dynamically generated at runtime using Reflection:

```
open System
open System.Reflection
open System.Reflection.Emit
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

/// Creates a dynamic module via reflection
let createModule () =
    let name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    let d = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    let a = d.DefineDynamicAssembly(AssemblyName(name), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run)
    a.DefineDynamicModule(name)
/// Creates a dynamic pair type using the specified x and y types
let createPairType (x:Type, y:Type) =
    let m = createModule()
    let t = m.DefineType("Pair", TypeAttributes.Public ||| TypeAttributes.Class)
    let x = t.DefineField(x.Name, x, FieldAttributes.Public)
    let y = t.DefineField(y.Name, y, FieldAttributes.Public)
    t.CreateType()
/// Creates a pair value using the specified pair type
let createPairValue (pairType:Type) (x:'X, y:'Y) =
    let instance = Activator.CreateInstance(pairType)
    pairType.GetField(typeof<'X>.Name).SetValue(instance, x)
    pairType.GetField(typeof<'Y>.Name).SetValue(instance, y)
    instance
/// Creates a cartesian product 
let createCartesianProduct (xs:'X seq, ys:'Y seq) =
    let pairType = createPairType (typeof<'X>,typeof<'Y>) 
    seq { for x in xs do for y in ys -> createPairValue pairType (x, y) }
/// Defines dynamic lookup operator for accessing a named field
let inline (?) (x:obj) name = x.GetType().GetField(name).GetValue(x)
/// Card suit discriminated union type
type Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade
/// Card rank discriminated union type 
type Rank = | One | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
            | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
/// Gets union case values
let getUnionValues<'T>() = 
    FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<'T>) 
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> FSharpValue.MakeUnion(x,[||]) :?> 'T)
let ranks, suits = getUnionValues<Rank>(), getUnionValues<Suit>()
/// Sequence of dynamically generated pairs
let cards = createCartesianProduct (ranks, suits)
// Paste this into F# interactive to print the generated cards
for card in cards do printfn "%A %A" card?Rank card?Suit
```

Comment: Incredible! Why is it so long???

Comment: The built-in .Net API for generating types dynamically via reflection is quite verbose. If you had a practical application for this you'd probably hide it behind a library.

Comment: There are only a couple of cases where I've found it useful to generate types dynamically in .Net (1) for mapping a plain text DSL to types for debugging in the [TickSpec](http://tickspec.codeplex.com) OSS project (2) for generating mock types against interfaces for unit testing in the [Foq](http://foq.codeplex.com) OSS project. To generate cards without reflection as a sequence of tuples simply do seq { for suit in suits do for rank in ranks do yield rank, suit }

Answer (score 3):

Taken from my (non-free) article [Structural Typing](http://fsharpnews.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/structural-typing.html) in the [F#.NET Journal](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/products/fsharp_journal/):

The following createType function creates a new .NET assembly, new module and new public class type of the given name:

```
> let createType typeName =
    let name = System.Reflection.AssemblyName(Name="tmpAssembly")
    let run = System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run
    let builder = System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(name, run)
    let mdl = builder.DefineDynamicModule "tmpModule"
    let attrs = TypeAttributes.Public ||| TypeAttributes.Class
    mdl.DefineType(typeName, attrs);;
val createType : string -> TypeBuilder
```